# Binding DOM Elements to Graphics Instead of SimpleMarkerSymbol()

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you let me know if it is possible to bind our custom DOM into the geometry point instead of ArcGIS API SimpleMarkerSymbol()?

I tried to do this like below but it is not doing the job!

```
var point = new Point(-126.687482, 54.793577); 
var pointSymbol = '<div class="marker"></div>'; 
var pointAttributes = {city: "Albuquerque",  state: "New Mexico"};
var pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Albuquerque"); 
var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol, pointAttributes).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
    thePoints.push(pointGraphic);
        console.log(thePoints)
map.on('load', function () {
        for (i = 0; i < thePoints.length; ++i) {
        map.graphics.add(thePoints[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Graphic() doesn't work that way.  The second parameter needs to be a subclass of https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/symbol-amd.html.